# List content of a directory in Spark code in Azure Synapse

Tags: scala, azure-synapse

In Databricks' Scala language, the command **dbutils.fs.ls** lists the content of a directory.  However, I'm working on a notebook in Azure Synapse and it doesn't have dbutils package.  What is a Spark command corresponding to dbutils.fs.ls?

```
%%scala
  dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://container@datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/outputs/wrangleddata")
```

```
%%spark
  // list the content of a directory. ????
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `mssparkutils`, it's a rough equivalent and the main documentation page is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-scala).  A simple example:

```
mssparkutils.fs.ls("/")
mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://container@datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/outputs/wrangleddata")
```